# iOS non-persistent data structures

Tags: ios, swift

I want to store a list of phone numbers in my app. There are currently 53 of them and I wish to store the following information.

- `Country`
- `TollNumber`
- `TollFreeNumber?`
- `TollNumber2?`
- `ISOCode`

It won't be updated very often and will likely be done manually for now, maybe by an API in the future. Persistent storage is not necessary. I'd normally just jam this in to a `[[String]]` Array or perhaps a `[[NSDictionary]]`, but I'm curious to know what the pros and cons are of the various non-persistent solutions out there.

For example would there be advantages/downsides to storing this in XML or JSON formats, are persistent solutions worth considering despite not needed persistence and are there Swift structures better suited to handling static data sets?

Comment: If you don't need to save the updates for your objects, so why not just simply create the instances at compile time? what's the purpose of mentioning the persistency?

Comment: @AhmadF I mention the lack of persistence only as there's a lot of questions on SO as well as in Apple's Documentation pertaining to the pros and cons of SQLite, CoreData, plists etc. I can't find the same information for non-persistent options.

Comment: If you don't have to persist any data, then I think you overthink about it, all you have to do it just declaring your variable and give them the desired values. Simply as `let myString = "Desired Value"`. Won't this be enough?

Comment: You might need to create a custom -struct- model, then create an array that contains the desired valued objects of that custom model...

Comment: @AhmadF I likely am overthinking things, most the solutions are pretty simple I'm just curious what most people do and whether there's pros and cons to each solution or what's generally considered the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in persisting the edits (CRUD) for the given information, creating a model to be a representation (template) of your data would be a good choise, for instance:

```
// of course determining what's the data type of each property is up to you,
// or even giving them an initial value...
struct MyModel {
    var country: String?
    var tollNumber: String?
    var TollFreeNumber: String?
    var TollNumber2: String?
    var ISOCode: String?
}


let containerArray = [MyModel(country: "country", tollNumber: "tollNumber", TollFreeNumber: "TollFreeNumber", TollNumber2: "TollNumber2", ISOCode: "ISOCode"),
                      MyModel(country: "country", tollNumber: "tollNumber", TollFreeNumber: "TollFreeNumber", TollNumber2: "TollNumber2", ISOCode: "ISOCode"),
                      MyModel(country: "country", tollNumber: "tollNumber", TollFreeNumber: "TollFreeNumber", TollNumber2: "TollNumber2", ISOCode: "ISOCode"), ...]
```

---

If you are required to read the given data from a file, I think that  *.plist* file would be a good choice, it is easy to work with from the end-users perspective, also check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193007/objc-plist-file-read-is-faster-then-json).

Although reading data directly from a struct instance -as mentioned in the first approach- should be better (speed wise), the benefit of working with a .plist file might be the *ease of editing*, all you have to do is replacing the updated file and that's it!

*Remark:* if we are talking about a small amount of data, speed issue won't be notable -almost- at all.

*Also:* if you are looking for a mechanism to persist data into your application, you might want to check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278194/how-to-make-offline-database-for-my-app/40278645).

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

One possible and easy to implement solution would be to convert your data into JSON and save that to the file system. It would allow you later to fetch the phoneNumbers from an API and just store them locally.

You could also look in storing them in a .plist file and reading from that. CoreData or Realm are in my opinion an overkill for your situation.